# Let $A = B(0,1)$ of $L^{p_1}[0,1]$. Why $\overline A$ is not a compact in $L^{p_2}[0,1]$ if $p_1 \gt p_2$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I've tried to use function $x(t)=t^{-\frac{1}{p_1}}$ and create a sequence $a_n$ such that:

1. $a_0 = 1$;
2. $a_n \lt a_{n-1}$;
3. $\|x\cdot I_{[a_n,a_{n-1}]}\|_{L^{p_1}}=1$.

In other words, I wanted to split $x$ to parts which are appropriate for $B(0,1)$. I've found that $a_n = e^{-n}$.
I hoped that sequence of functions $f_n = x\cdot I_{[a_n,a_{n-1}]}$ would have subsequence where $\|f_n-f_k\|_{L^{p_2}} \ge C$. Actually there is no such $C$ other than 0. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a sketch for another solution.
Let's look at the sequence of functions $x_n = \frac{1}{(\ln n)^\frac{1}{p_1}} t^{-\frac{1}{p_1}}I_{(\frac{1}{n},1)}(t)$.
It's easy to check that all $x_n$ are in $\overline{B(0,1)}$ of $L^{p_1}[0,1]$.
After that we use the criterion of pre-compactness in $L^{p_1}[0,1]$.
We need to prove that $\forall \epsilon >0 \space \exists \delta >0 \space \forall x \in M \space h \in [0,\delta]$ $$\int_h^1 |x(t-h)-x(t)|^{p_2} dt< \epsilon$$
is wrong for $M=A$.
So we need to separate our integral from zero.
We take $x_n = x$ and estimate difference using Lagrange theorem for $f(s)=s^{-p_1}$. and take $s = f(t)$.